# javascript(html) while loop not working after trying to limit guess

Tags: javascript, html

my main aim is to stop the program if the user guess the number 5 times **OR** when the user guess the correct answer, the program should end too.

```
function abc()
{
    var guessbutton = document.getElementById("guessbutton");
    var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
    var maxtries = 5;
    var count = 0;
var secret = 10;
    
while (count < 6)
{

if (guess == secret) 
{
document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "correct";
guessbutton.disabled=true;
break;
}
else if (guess > secret) 
{
document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "too high";
}
else if (guess < secret) 
{
document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "too low";
}

else
{document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "max try";
guessbutton.disabled=true;
break;
}
count++;
}
}
```

the problem i am facing with this code is that it will continue even after 5 tries.
i am assuming the error is due to `count++;` not working correctly

this is my html code

```
<input id="guess" type="text" name="guess">
<button id="guessbutton" type="button" onclick="return abc()">Guess</button>
<p id="feedback"></p>
```

Comment: You aren't using maxtries. And also, as does the program stop at 7? Does it let you try infinite times or 7?

Comment: Unclear how you expect the input to be updated in a while loop

Comment: @AlePlo infinite times, it will not stop until guess==secret

Comment: You're referring to more HTML elements than just the button. Please create a [mre]. Also, a command like `var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;` will not extend into the future, `guess` is not updated automatically when the user changes the input's value.

Comment: @epascarello hi sorry about that, missed out 1 line. i have updated the code

Comment: This seems like it's been built expecting a `prompt()` to provide the value, rather than an input (As prompts pause JS execution and return a value) you will need to reconsider your approach to do this without executing-halting input.

Comment: Here's fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/m93t6wf2/

Comment: @ChrisG thank you so much! i have tried it and it fit into my code! however, will you be able to advice how can i keep the feedbacks? 
for example after 1st input, its too low. on the screen will show "too low", after 2nd input, it is too high, **instead of** showing **only** "too high", how can i show "too low, too high". and this adds on after every try

Comment: Something like `feedback.innerHTML += "too high<br>";` will do it.

Comment: okay! i will try that, thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the while loop. You are just looping without allowing the user to update the input textbox. You should be checking the count on every click.

```js
var guessbutton = document.getElementById("guessbutton");
var count = 0;
var maxTries = 5;
var secret = 10;

function abc() {
  var guess = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);
  count++;
  console.log(count);
  if (guess == secret) {
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "correct";
    guessbutton.disabled = true;
  } else if (guess > secret) {
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "too high";
  } else if (guess < secret) {
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "too low";
  } 
  if (count >= maxTries) {
    document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "max try";
    guessbutton.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="guess" type="text" name="guess">
<button id="guessbutton" type="button" onclick="return abc()">Guess</button>
<p id="feedback"></p>
```

Comment: thank you, will you be able to explain why should i declare the var outside function? it seems to not work when i put them inside the function.

Comment: because each time you call the function what does it do? It redeclares the variable.